# Placed image sharp in Master but not on Page?

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I've also asked this over on the subreddit, as it's fairly urgent (last minute change before sending to print) but I'm not sure it will get picked up there.

Hi there

Fairly basic user of indesign so not a pro or anything, so I'm hoping someone could help me work this out.

I have a screen grab [here](https://imgur.com/a/s7srNAD) of the issue. Basically, the placed image is sharp in the master but when i go to the page it's really pixel-y. The high quality pdf export is even worse (even taking the normal amount of loss into account).

I've checked the display settings (set to high quality for both the overall and the specific image), there are no further transformations happening to the image on the page (as it's inherited from the master), i've tried changing my view settings (i.e. checking with different previews). I've tried embedding it.

Unfortuntely the image resolution is what it is (it isn't mine) so I can't change that, but since it's sharp in the master I feel like the problem is somwhere in my indesign settings?

How do I fix this?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the file. I would check to make sure the image is linked. Make sure there are not 2 instances of the same image but one is not linked in the file. Does the image look OK if you place the image in a new file? Try exporting with a different PDF setting. Does the image look pixelated in InDesign if you change the preview to high quality?